# what is this facebook code?

Tags: javascript

Inspecting what facebook is doing in my navigator, I see this code:

```
for (;;);{"t":"refresh"}
```

If you try to evaluate it, you can figure what happens (infinite loop).

Do you Know what it is?

Comment: At first glance, I thought it was an infinite loop, but the `;` after the `)` I think would end the loop after the first iteration. So maybe there's an error in your copy+paste?

Comment: It may be helpful for you to know that the English word for *bucle* is *loop*.

Comment: @Syntactic: Interesting. What language was `bucle` from?

Comment: @FrustratedWithFormsDesigner  I rewrite the code with the exact sentence from FB.

I'm catalan, in spanish and catalan a loop is named bucle, I thought that it was correct in english.

Comment: @FrustratedWithFormsDesigner: Catalan, Espanol...in French it's *boucle*.

Comment: Interesting.  This is basically a forced infinite loop followed by an unassigned object literal.  It doesn't make much sense at all.  The fact that they are on the same line could be due to minification and something might be following the literal (such as a prototype method or something else).  Which page did you bump into this code on, and which browser were you using?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Am I correct if this was inside the response from an ajax call?

This is a one of the strategies employed to avoid [XSS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting) when dynamically adding scripts that contain user-specific content.
If it had not been here, an [evil] page could have requested this script inside a regular script tag, and have access to the methods and objects defined by it.

The code loading this script from Facebook using xhr will remove the first section before evaluating it to get its content. It this case the result would be `{"t":"refresh"}`.

A script from a different domain is not able to do this.

Comment: +1 definitely what's happening. This is one of the common ways of blocking cross-site-script-inclusion. Another would be prefixing the content with a comment marker.

Comment: Perfect, that would be very usefull for my sites!